# dragablz TabablzControl not activate tabpage/view on RequestNavigate

Tags: wpf, prism, tabcontrol

When the view is registered it shown for the first time, but If I try to view it after loading other views on tabablzcontroll it not navigate to that previous one. the view creation policy is shared one

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
```

Assume IsActive=true

```
private void ResourceShow()
    {
        if (IsActive)
        {
            if (!regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion].Views.Contains("vResource"))//WPFApp.View.uEmployeeView
            {
                regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, typeof(vResource));
            }
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, "vResource");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works when I did like this   ((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion].Views.OfType<vResource>().SingleOrDefault().Parent).IsSelected = true;
              but I am not satisfied with the solution, Is it possible to add it to regionadapter ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the TabControl as the Region.

```
<TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="SearchRegion" />
```

When registering the module

```
_container.RegisterType<object, MoviesView>(nameof(MoviesView));
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("SearchRegion", typeof (MoviesView));
```

And navigation

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(
                    "SearchRegion",
                    new Uri("MoviesView", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: The course where tell about it [Prism Problems & Solutions: Mastering TabControl](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-mastering-tabcontrol/table-of-contents)

Comment: I had did this, but dear its not tabcontrol i am talking about , its dragzable tabcontrol,  region have been created  as <dragablz:TabablzControl x:Name="MainTabControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainContentRegion}">
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
                <dragablz:InterTabController InterTabClient="{Binding TabClient}"/>
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>

Comment: Also module and view registration have been done,  if (!regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion].Views.Contains("vResource"))//WPFApp.View.uEmployeeView
                {
                    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, typeof(vResource));
                }
                regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, "vResource");

Comment: the only way I can activate tab is by replacing the code   egionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, "vResource"); with  ((System.Windows.Controls.TabItem)regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentR‌​egion].Views.OfType<vResource>().SingleOrDefault().Parent).IsSelected = true;